# how to deal with the None Type in keras?

Tags: keras

I want to train my model but I do not know why the name_list result is None
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwUDM.png)

if I ignore and treat the list as X directly, the result will become:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OhQH.png)

And this is my code:

```
def name_method1(input):
    input = input.lower()

    output = []
    amount = []

    letter_order=[' ', 'a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
                  'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '-', '\'',
                  '.', ',', '(',')']


    for character in input:
        if character not in letter_order:
            break
        num = letter_order.index(character)
        amount += character

        if len(amount) > 30:
            break

        output.append(num)
        leng = len(output)
    while leng < 30:
        leng += 1
        output.append("0")

    print(output)
    return output
result_list = []
with open("athletes.csv", 'r') as f:
    dataset = csv.reader(f)
    next(dataset)
    for row in dataset:
        name = row[0]
        nationality = row[1]
        name_list = name_method2(name)
        result_list.append(name_list)
    f.close()

print(result_list)

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, steps_per_epoch=1)

_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)

print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

how to correct it?

Comment: please explain your problem more specifically and tell us what you are trying to do! And it is easier to solve the problem if you can create a [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Don't ignore it and get rid of the lines which contain `None`. So something like `if None in name_list: continue`, in order to not append `name_list` to `result_list` in this case.